# Clean-up database connection with SQLAlchemy in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

With Pandas, I can very easily read data from a database into a dataframe:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas


query = 'SELECT * FROM Table_Name;'
engine = create_engine('...')

df = pandas.read_sql_query(query, engine)

print(df.head())
```

I would like to make sure that no connection is kept open after executing `.read_sql_query()`, no matters if the query succeeded or if it raised an exception.

I am currently:

- Using a function to restrict the engine's scope. I only expect to call this function once each half an hour, so I do not mind re-creating the engine if that helps ensuring everything is cleaned/closed/garbage-collected.
- Disabling pooling with `poolclass=NullPool`.
- Finally calling `engine.disponse()`.

Like so:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.pool import NullPool
import pandas


def get_data():
    query = 'SELECT * FROM Table_Name;'
    try:
        engine = create_engine('...', poolclass=NullPool)
        df = pandas.read_sql_query(query, engine)
    finally:
        engine.dispose()
    return df


print(get_data().head())
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

#### Backgrounds:

When using `sqlalchemy` with pandas `read_sql_query(query, con)` method, it will create a `SQLDatabase` object with an attribute `connectable` to [`self.connectable.execute(query)`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.23.3/pandas/io/sql.py#L954). And the `SQLDatabase.connectable` is initialized as `con` as long as [it is an instance of `sqlalchemy.engine.Connectable`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.23.3/pandas/io/sql.py#L508) (i.e. [`Engine` and `Connection`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Connectable)).

#### Case I: when passing `Engine` object as `con`

Just as example code in your question:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd
engine = create_engine('...')
df = pd.read_sql_query(query, con=engine)
```

Internally, pandas just use `result = engine.execute(query)`, [which means](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#basic-usage):

> Where above, the `execute()` method acquires a new `Connection` on its own, executes the statement with that object, and returns the `ResultProxy`. In this case, the ResultProxy contains a special flag known as `close_with_result`, which indicates that when its underlying DBAPI cursor is closed, the `Connection` object itself is also closed, which again **returns the DBAPI connection to the connection pool**, releasing transactional resources.

In this case, you don't have to worry about the `Connection` itself, which is closed automatically, but it will keep the connection pool of `engine`.

So you can either disable pooling by using:

```
engine = create_engine('...', poolclass=NullPool)
```

or `dispose` the engine entirely with `engine.dispose()` at the end.

But following the [Engine Disposal doc (the last paragraph)](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#engine-disposal), these two are alternative, you don't have to use them at the same time. So in this case, for simple one-time usage of `read_sql_query` and clean-up, I think this should be enough:

```
# Clean up entirely after every query.
engine = create_engine('...')
df = pd.read_sql_query(query, con=engine)
engine.dispose()
```

---

#### Case II: when passing `Connection` object as `con`:

```
connection = engine.connect()
print(connection.closed) # False
df = pd.read_sql_query(query, con=connection)
print(connection.closed) # False again
# do_something_else(connection)
connection.close()
print(connection.closed) # True
engine.dispose()
```

> You should do this whenever you want greater control over attributes of the connection, when it gets closed, etc. For example, a very import example of this is a `Transaction`, which lets you decide when to commit your changes to the database. ([from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42772654/2303761))

But with pandas, we have no control inside the `read_sql_query`, the only usefulness of `connection` is that it allows you to do more useful things before we explicitly close it.

---

#### So generally speaking:

I think I would like to use following pattern, which gives me more control of connections and leaves the future extensibility:

```
engine = create_engine('...')
# Context manager makes sure the `Connection` is closed safely and implicitly
with engine.connect() as conn:
    df = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn)
    print(conn.in_transaction()) # False
    # do_something_with(conn)
    trans = conn.begin()
    print(conn.in_transaction()) # True
    # do_whatever_with(trans)
    print(conn.closed) # False
print('Is Connection with-OUT closed?', conn.closed) # True
engine.dispose()
```

But for simple usage cases such as your example code, I think both ways are equally clean and simple for clean-up DB IO resources.

Comment: I see you create a connection named `conn`, but you do not use it to read the dataframe, you pass the engine as parameter to `read_sql_query()`. How would that help then? It seems the context manager is mananing a connection that is never used. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Peque Sorry, that's a typo. And actually passing `engine` will also works, but that's different. Check out there differences [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34322471/2303761).

Comment: @Peque I think there might be some confusion when combining the SQLAlchemy context management with pandas SQL IO usage, so after some more digging, I rewrite my answer entirely. Hope that can help, and correct me if I am wrong :)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I have tested and even after the connection is closed (`connection.close()`), it is still present on the table `sys.sysprocesses` (of the database) throughout the execution of the script.
Thus, if the script (after the connection) lasts another 10 minutes, the connection remains present on the sys.sysprocesses table for 10 minutes.

I think it is significant to draw attention to this fact: connection closed YES, process in the database closed NO.

Here are some scripts I used for testing:

```
sql = "select * from tbltest"
s_con = '...' #connection information

con = URL.create("mssql+pyodbc", query={"odbc_connect": s_con})
engine = create_engine(con)

with engine.connect() as con:
    frame = pd.read_sql(sql=sql, con=con)
    print(con.closed) # False

print(con.closed) # True
engine.dispose()

from time import sleep
sleep(20) # Pause for 20 seconds to launch the query with SSMS
```

Use of SSMS

```
Query for check connection
SELECT * FROM sys.sysprocesses
```