# SQLAlchemy core engine.execute() vs connection.execute()

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy

I'm playing around with SQLAlchemy core in Python, and I've read over the documentation numerous times and still need clarification about `engine.execute()` vs `connection.execute()`.

As I understand it, `engine.execute()` is the same as doing `connection.execute()`, followed by `connection.close()`.

The tutorials I've followed let me to use this in my code:

Initial setup in script

```
try:
    engine = db.create_engine("postgres://user:pass@ip/dbname", connect_args={'connect_timeout': 5})
    connection = engine.connect()
    metadata = db.MetaData()
except exc.OperationalError:
    print_error(f":: Could not connect to {db_ip}!")
    sys.exit()
```

Then, I have functions that handle my database access, for example:

```
def add_user(a_username):
    query = db.insert(table_users).values(username=a_username)
    connection.execute(query)
```

Am I supposed to be calling `connection.close()` before my script ends? Or is that handled efficiently enough by itself? Would I be better off closing the connection at the end of `add_user()`, or is that inefficient?

If I do need to be calling `connection.close()` before the script ends, does that mean interrupting the script will cause hanging connections on my Postgres DB?

Answer (score 1):

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34322471/sqlalchemy-engine-connection-and-session-difference) helpful to better understand the different interaction paradigms in sqlalchemy, in case you haven't read it yet.

Regarding your question as to when to close your db connection: It is indeed very inefficient to create and close connections for every statement execution. However you should make sure that your application does not have connection leaks in it's global flow.