# Why we need to define engine and connections in SQLAlchemy Flask?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm writing APIs in flask, and i'm asking myself if i use SQLAlchemy in a functional but wrong way.

Currently my app is like

```
# File app.__init__.py

db = SQLAlchemy()
app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=False)

def create_app():


    app.config.from_object("config.Config")

    CORS(app)
    db.init_app(app)
```

So i don't initialize any engine.

```
# File app.core.core.py


from flask import current_app
from app import db
...

# Blueprint Configuration
core_bp = Blueprint("core_bp", __name__)

# Swagger documentation configuration
authorizations = {"apikey": {"type": "apiKey", "in": "header", "name": "Authorization"}}

api = Api(core_bp, authorizations=authorizations)
ns = api.namespace("auth", description="User Authentification APIs")

...

@ns.route("/signup", methods=["POST"])
class SignupApi(Resource):
    """
    Enpoint for sign up of users
    """

    @api.expect(resource_fields_signup)
    @api.doc(
        responses={400: "error", 201: "error",}
    )
    def post(self):

        json_data = request.get_json()
        if not json_data:
            return make_response(jsonify({"error": "no data"}), 400)
        
        ...

        user = User(email=email,role=role,confirmed=confirmed,password=password,first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, tel_number=tel_number_formatted,active=active)
        
        try:
            db.session.add(user)
            db.session.commit()

        except:
            return make_response(
                jsonify({"error": "cant't add user to data base"}), 400
            )

        
        return make_response(
            jsonify(
                {
                    "success": "user created, mail confirmation sent",
                    "User id": user.id,
                    "User email": user.email,
                }
            ),
            201,
        )

...
```

```
# File app.core.models.py

from app import db
from app import bcrypt
from flask_bcrypt import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
import datetime

class User(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    registered_on = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False)
    admin = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)
    tel_number = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    confirmed = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)
    confirmed_on = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=True)
    role = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    password_reset_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=True)
    last_login_on = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=True)

    def __init__(
        self,
        email,
        first_name,
        last_name,
        password,
        confirmed,
        active,
        role,
        tel_number,
        admin=False,
        confirmed_on=None,
    ):
        self.email = email
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.password_hash = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(password).decode("utf-8")
        self.registered_on = datetime.datetime.now()
        self.admin = admin
        self.tel_number = tel_number
        self.role = role
        self.confirmed = confirmed
        self.confirmed_on = confirmed_on
        self.active = active

    def hash_password(self, password):
        self.password_hash = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(password).decode("utf-8")

    def check_password(self, password):
        return check_password_hash(self.password_hash, password)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<User {}>".format(self.email)
```

It works, but i had some errors with DB, which i can't repeat. So where my question is.

I use

```
db.session.add(user)
db.session.commit()
```

And for queries:

```
user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first_or_404()
```

Must I use engine? Why? because it works without difining engine.. Must i use connections?
I found the official documentation (https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/engines_connections.html) , but i don't really understand if it is necessary and what is the right way to use connections.

Comment: So you have installed postgres on your machine and have created a DB in postgres. But now you need to query and persist data in that DB. The very first thing is to establish a connection to the DB and that's what `db = SQLAlchemy()` is doing with the help of `create_engine()` function. Of course if you dont provide any parameter (because you havent set any on your postgres config) it will connect with default settings but you will get error due to incorrect DB name

Comment: my config is described in :
`app.config.from_object("config.Config")`

Comment: I’m not very sure about your question. Maybe these links can be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34322471/sqlalchemy-engine-connection-and-session-difference/42772654
     or            https://hackingandslacking.com/demystifying-flasks-application-context-c7bd31a53817