# How to properly close and open connections with two different hosts using sqlalchemy in Python?

Tags: python, mysql, database, sqlalchemy

Basically, I don't need to do anything fancy. I'm just trying to remote connect to a MySQL database, pull it into a pandas dataframe, do some work, and then I want to output that as a table, but this time, to a local database, all formatted with MySQL and using Python. I'm incredibly confused about sessions, engines, connections, and the like for SQLAlchemy, and frankly I'm not sure I really need any deep functionality. When I've done it in the past with R, it was simply a matter of explicitly closing the old connection and doing the exact same thing with a new one.

However, as far as I can tell, there's no dedicated way to close connections that I have been able to understand (for example [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34322471/sqlalchemy-engine-connection-and-session-difference) went way over my head).

I really only need a single pandas.read_sql() command to retrieve a table, and a single to.sql() command to write the table. What I have so far is below.

But this is with only a single database. Where do I put some sort of disconnect statement? Can the "engines" run simultaneously? Should I be using cursor, or execute, or some sort of other type of interfacing with SQL?

```
hostname = "remote.server.com"
username = "user"
password = "pass"
database = "mydb"

engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://{user}:{pw}@{host}/{db}".format(host=hostname, db=database, user=username, pw=password))

getcommand = "SELECT * FROM table"

df = pd.read_sql(getcommand, engine)

#work with the df

df.to_sql(name="dbname", con=engine, if_exists="replace", index=False)
```

Comment: " I want to output that as a table, but this time, to a local database" if you want it to be a different databsae, why are you passing the same engine at `con=engine` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need the remote connection open at the same time as the local connection since you might be reading while still writing with pandas.

Something like this should work.  I think it is probably better to wrap your sql string in `text` too.

```py
#... define remote and local connection variables
# other imports

from sqlalchemy.sql import text

remote_engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://{user}:{pw}@{host}/{db}".format(host=remote_hostname, db=remote_database, user=remote_username, pw=remote_password))

local_engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://{user}:{pw}@{host}/{db}".format(host=local_hostname, db=local_database, user=local_username, pw=local_password))

getcommand = text("SELECT * FROM table")

# remote (SA) connection returned to engine(pool) after end of with block
with remote_engine.connect() as remote_conn:
    df = pd.read_sql(getcommand, remote_conn)

    # local (SA) connection returned to engine(pool) after end of with block
    # begin will cause transaction to automatically commit unless
    # an exception occurs.
    with local_engine.connect() as local_conn, local_conn.begin():
        df.to_sql(name="dbname", con=local_conn, if_exists="replace", index=False)

# db api connections closed when script ends when everything goes out of scope and is garbage collected
```

Comment: Very interesting. So it's not really necessary to explicitly close connections, only to be careful when opening them? I wasn't aware the garbage collection did most of the heavy lifting. I assume I should put my work in the middle, after the first with statement?

Comment: Well without drowning in the details, the with statements do `close` the connections by returning them to the engine pool but the underlying dbapi connection might not be closed because opening and closing those is costly.

Comment: Yes sorry, work in the middle unless you need to access local db.